# Finding the primary keys from functional dependency of relationship R

Tags: sql

The relationship is R(A, B, C, D) and the functional dependencies:

- A -> BCD
- BC -> AD
- D -> B

My attempt at this question is first decompose the first functional dependence into: A -> B, A -> C, A -> D. Then I see the second functional dependency as BC -> AD = AA -> AD so A -> D. Then the only primary key should be A.

However, the answer is that the keys are A and BC. I don't understand what is the problem. Could anyone help me by pointing out my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that they are asking out for the candidate keys. Then BC and A should be the candidate keys.

A remains the primary key.